# How to fix deadlock while sending a few MB file via tcp socket?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to send file via raw tcp socket.
When I send files smaller than defined buffer, it works.
When I send 10MB files and tcp no delay option is on, server hangs on reading last chunk.
It never happen when I send that file at once(increasing buffer size).
Here is my code.

Client is Xamarin Forms, server is c++/cli.

I'm thinking of race conditions, deadlocks.

Client

```
private async Task SendBigFile(Stream stream)
        {
                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(this.ns, Encoding.UTF8, true))
                {
                    const int bufferSize = 65535;
                    long bytesLeft = stream.Length;
                    while (bytesLeft > 0)
                    {
                        var dataSize = (int)Math.Min(bytesLeft, bufferSize);
                        var data = new byte[dataSize];
                        var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, dataSize);
                        if (bytesRead != 0)
                        {
                            bw.Write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                            bw.Flush();
                            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                }
        }
```

Server

```
void receiveBigFile(unsigned int length, System::IO::Stream^ stream)
{
    const System::Int64 bufferSize = 65535;
    System::Int64 bytesLeft = length, bytes = 0;
    System::IO::BinaryReader^ br = nullptr;
    try
    {
        br = gcnew System::IO::BinaryReader(this->ns, System::Text::Encoding::UTF8, true);
        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {
                System::Int32 dataSize = System::Math::Min(bytesLeft, bufferSize);
                array<System::Byte>^ data = gcnew array<System::Byte>(dataSize);
                System::Int64 bytesRead = br->Read(data, 0, data->Length);
                if (bytesRead != 0)
                {
                    stream->Write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
                }
                else
                    break;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (br != nullptr)
        {
            br->Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Reuse the same `var data = new byte[dataSize];` buffer for all chunks.

Comment: Why don't you send the size of the file (so the server knows the exact length) before sending the bytes? (like a little header)

Comment: Like Jeroen said. I'd use a fixed bufferSize that is multiple of 4 (e.g. 65532). Add logging server-side. Verify length is correct. Attempt to read full bufferSize even when there aren't that many bytes left. **Exit loop if 0 bytes read.**

Comment: Consider using [System.IO.Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines)

Comment: This whole function could be reduced to `private async Task SendBigFile(Stream stream) => await stream.CopyToAsync(this.ns);`

Comment: Why ever dynamic buffer size in the end causes hanging? @JeroenvanLangen

Comment: It doesn't make sense, does it hang client or server side.

Comment: It hangs on last chunk. Client sends last chunk  Server receives a dozen or so bytes less and wait for missing bytes which never arrive. I wonder why it might or might not depend on top no delay. Probably Android bug?

Comment: The number of missing bytes is not constant and I'm getting more and more frustrated. Client connects to server via local wifi.

Comment: Did you try `CopyTo` or `CopyToAsync`, rather than using the above inefficient and possibly incorrect code.

Comment: Inefficient?  Yes I tried. I noticed Microsoft c++ runtime exception in output console and sometimes invalid parameter passed to c runtime always when c++ cli server hangs.